# Kohana Logs file writable but permission denied

Tags: php, kohana

I have checked the install.php and it gives me the green light on the logs file. However, my application gets an error saying

```
ErrorException [ 2 ]: file_put_contents(/my/app/path/logs/2013/03/04.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied ~ SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Log/File.php [ 90 ]
```

Comment: odds are the folder `logs/2013/03` doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

I am also faced the same issue,i solved it with help of below comment to make all sub directories writable.

```
 chmod -R 777 cache/ logs/
```

This may help future referrer.

Answer (score 0):

Even if `logs/` directory exists and have proper permissions set, it's subdirectories (like `logs/2013/` and `logs/2013/03`) could have improper permissions, for example due to some file copying or so...
Be sure that **all** subdirectories allow **writting** for `user`/`group`/`other`.